# sys_write doesn't print message to the terminal

Tags: system, programming, assembler

I'm trying to explore GNU Assembler using this example: https://0xax.github.io/asm_1/

My code main.s is

```
 .data
 message: .ascii "ASSEMBLY OUTPUT"

.text
.globl _start

_start:
movq $1, %rdi
movq $1, %rax
movq $15, %rdx
movq $message, %rsi
syscall
movq $60, %rax
movq $0, %rdi
syscall
```

Command line preparation:

> as -g -o main.o main.s
>
> ld -o main main.o

Now, I run ./main
But it doesn't print anything and terminal is waiting my next command.

What's going wrong?

In GNU Debugger numbers were successfully stored in registers.

I see result of first syscall "-14" in RAX.

Comment: It ***does*** print the expected output in my system. However, since there is no newline in the output, you may have missed it. I suggest adding `\n` at the end of `OUTPUT` and changing the length from 15 to 16 in the `movq $15, %rdx` line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest adding newlines to the output string, so it stands out. Please, try the following version:

```
.data
message: .ascii "\nASSEMBLY OUTPUT\n\n"
msglen = . - message

.text
.globl _start

_start:
movq $1, %rdi
movq $1, %rax
movq $msglen, %rdx
movq $message, %rsi
syscall
movq $60, %rax
movq $0, %rdi
syscall
```